# Evaluation of $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\left(2^{x^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{e^x}}-\left(3^{x^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{e^x}}}{x^n}\;,$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluation of $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\left(2^{x^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{e^x}}-\left(3^{x^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{e^x}}}{x^n}\;,$$ Where $n\in \mathbb{N}$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ $$l=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{e^{\ln (2)^{\frac{x^n}{e^x}}}-e^{\ln(3)^{\frac{x^n}{e^x}}}}{x^n} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{e^{\frac{x^n}{e^x}\ln 2}-e^{\frac{x^n}{e^x}\ln 3}}{x^n}$$

Now How can I solved it after that , Help Required, Thanks

Comment: The numerator approaches $0$ (both expressions approach $1$), and the denominator approaches $\infty$, so why  can't you solve it after that?

Comment: Perhaps that means $x→0$?

Answer (score 4):

You only need to rewrite it to

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2^{\frac{x^n}{e^x}} - 3^{\frac{x^n}{e^x}}}{x^n}$$

Now you can see that

- $$\lim_{x\to\infty} 2^{\frac{x^n}{e^x}} - 3^{\frac{x^n}{e^x}} = \lim_{x\to\infty} 2^{\frac{x^n}{e^x}} - \lim_{x\to\infty}3^{\frac{x^n}{e^x}} = 2^{\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^n}{e^x}} - 3^{\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^n}{e^x}} = 0$$
- $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^n = \infty$

So the total limit is "$\frac{0}{\infty}$" which is $0$.